# Unresolved External Symbol C++

Tags: c++

I have read [this informative stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12573816/what-is-an-undefined-reference-unresolved-external-symbol-error-and-how-do-i-fix) regarding unresolved external symbols, but I am still not sure how to solve my issue.

Within Visual Studio 2012, I have a solution consisting of multiple projects, one of which is a static library called common. Each project that produces an executable consists of a header and associated cpp file of all global functions used throughout that specific program, called programglobals. In the process of developing one of these projects, I started duplicating some of this code from one project's programglobals to another. Now that I have completed all the projects, I want to extract the duplicate code into a associated header and cpp file within the common library, but I believe I might be referencing them incorrectly, which is producing these unresolved external symbol errors

Here is a dumbed down example of what I am currently attempting.

Common Library Files

```
//solutionglobals.h
void commonFunction();

//solutionglobals.cpp
void commonFunction() {
    int asdf;
}
```

Project A Files

```
// programglobals.h
#include "../common/solutionglobals.h

void functionUsedInProjectA();

// programglobals.cpp
void functionUsedInProjectA() {
    int x;
}

// output.h 
#include "programglobals.h"
void asdfA();

// output.cpp
void asdfA() {
    int x;
    functionUsedInProjectA();
    commonFunction();
}
```

Project B Files

```
// programglobals.h
#include "../common/solutionglobals.h

void functionUsedInProjectB();

// programglobals.cpp
void functionUsedInProjectB() {
    int x;
}

// output.h 
#include "programglobals.h"
void asdfB();

// output.cpp
void asdfB() {
    int x;
    functionUsedInProjectB();
    commonFunction();
}
```

Any reference to `commonFunction()` results in an unresolved external symbol error.

Thanks!

Comment: Do you mean `commonFunction()` ?

Comment: For a question like that, it is necessary to show exact compilation commands and exact compilation error. You are just compiling/linking it wrong, thus the problem.

Comment: You will have to specify in your executable projects that they reference the static lib. May be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235627%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#uselibinapp helps (lower third of the article).

Comment: @Oncaphillis That was the solution. I was not adding it as a reference. Feel free to post that as an answer and I will select it as the solution. Thanks for your help - I am still getting used to Visual Studio.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will have to specify in your executable projects that they reference the static lib. May be http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ms235627%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#uselibinapp helps (lower third of the article).

> Before you can use the math routines in the static library, you must
>   reference it. To do this, open the shortcut menu for the MyExecRefsLib
>   project in Solution Explorer, and then choose References. In the
>   MyExecRefsLib Property Pages dialog box, expand the Common Properties
>   node, select Framework and References, and then choose the Add New
>   Reference button.

Comment: Might be nitpicking, but it might be an idea to add *how* to reference the static library. At the moment your answer *sort of* borders as link-only.

Answer (score 0):

The linker cannot 'see' your function and as such thinks that it does not have an `external symbol` referencing it, hence the error.

You must `#pragma comment(lib, [library here])` to reference the external function.

The following code can be used to reproduce this error:

[header file- test.h]:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"

void someOtherFunction();
void someFunction(string thisVar);
```

[code file- test.cpp]:

```
#include "StdAfx.h"
#include "test.h"

void someOtherFunction()
{
    printf("Hello World!");
}
```

[function body for `someFunction(string thisVar)` is missing!]